# Why can't I instance a chromeoptions object with selenium in powershell?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Powershell v5.1 on a Windows 10 machine to automate chrome tasks with Selenium chromedriver, and I'm having trouble creating a ChromeOptions object in PS after importing all the relevant dlls. Every source I've found says the correct object instantiation is done thus:

```
ChromeOptions options = new Chromeoptions();
```

But that results in this error:

```
At line:1 char:43
+ chromeoptions options = new chromeoptions();
+                                           ~
An expression was expected after '('.
     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

This is after I've imported these:

```
add-type -path "D:\\selenium\selenium.webdriverbackedselenium.dll"
add-type -path "D:\\selenium\thoughtworks.selenium.core.dll"
add-type -path "D:\\selenium\webdriver.support.dll"
add-type -path "D:\\selenium\webdriver.support.dll"
```

Am I missing any dlls required to instantiate chromeoptions objects? I can open chrome fine with chromedriver and navigate normally, but I need to configure some things before it opens or it's essentially useless to me. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally started playing with Selenium today because i want to try and scrape dynamic loaded data (javascript). Anyway

You are copying C# code and expecting it to work. You need to convert it to PS code (or run is as C# code in PS)

```
ChromeOptions options = new Chromeoptions();
```

becomes

```
$chromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
```

$chromeOptions now has methods and properties that you can access, such as AddArgument for instance.

Once you created your ChromeOptions-object, you need to add it to the driver.

```
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($chromeOptions)
```